# Jasmine calling beforeEach after tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, coffeescript, jasmine

I'm writing a Rails app which has the following jasmine spec:

```
describe "buttons", ->

  beforeEach ->
    loadFixtures("foo.html")
    alert("beforeEach: " + $("tr.foo").length)

  describe ".hide_foo", ->
    alert(".hide-foo: " + $("tr.foo").length)
    ...
    expect($("tr.foo")).toBeHidden()
```

The spec failed with the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'expect' of null
```

So I put in the alerts. First we see ".hide-foo: 0", and then after I close that "beforeEach: 44" comes up. So clearly the error is because we're calling the `expect` before the fixture is loaded but...why the heck isn't `beforeEach` executed *before each* example?

I'm using jasminerice to use the Rails Asset Pipeline to compile my Coffeescript. Versions:

```
$ bundle show jasmine && bundle show jasminerice
/home/tmacdonald/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/jasmine-1.2.0
/home/tmacdonald/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/jasminerice-0.0.9
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`describe` blocks should not have testing logic directly inside them. You should put all of your testing logic inside of an `it` block.

```
describe ".hide_foo", ->
    it 'should hide the row', ->
        alert(".hide-foo: " + $("tr.foo").length)

        expect($("tr.foo")).toBeHidden()
```

Comment: Goodness gracious, I need more sleep. Thank you. I'll see myself out now.